# What did Madara mean by "showing our guts"?

Tags: naruto

In the latest episode (filler, obviously...) of Naruto Shippuden, episode 368 the expression

> "to show your guts"

was flying all over the place. I've tried Googling around, but didn't manage to find what it meant.

---

I think it means something along the lines of *showing your most inner feelings*, but I'm not entirely certain.

PS: English isn't my native language, so don't judge.

Comment: Not a phrase I'm familiar with. It may be something referring to "show your strength", since "having guts" can mean being strong or courageous.

Comment: Think it might be a bit off due to translation. But showing our guts means something similar to showing our true colors. No secrets, nothing to hide. So that you can be trusted in total without any form of doubt.

Comment: I just took a glance at the episode; this is a literal word-for-word translation of 腸を見せる "to show guts/entrails/innards". Pretty sure OP's inference that it means something like "showing your innermost feelings" is more or less correct.

Comment: Side note, I don't think this episode is filler. These episodes were actually based off the manga.

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly, the manga translation says "resolve" instead of "guts", so when Madara says, "It's OK, Hashirama, I've seen your final resolve", it makes more sense than "guts".

Comment: dude you all have it wrong. when he says that showing your guts thing he literaly means you cant show someone your actual guts.basically meaning you cant truly tell how someone feels or truly know if someone is on your side or how they think,since your not them. you cant see a persons guts because it cant be shown; unless your stomach is ripped open that is.

Answer (score 2):

From context and the discussions in the show about the reasons that wars persist and continue (bits and pieces from Nagato, Naruto & Jiraiya at different points in time) - they are talking about how people cannot discern emotions and thoughts of others directly, meaning people cannot know the true feelings of others. Which in turn causes misunderstanding, differences in opinion and emotion to the end result of conflict, culminating in war.

Given this overall theme, I think it is reasonable to understand this (possibly mistranslated phrase) to mean - show our internal feelings/emotions/thoughts to the other (internal  <-> guts).

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Advanced Learners English Dictionary defines guts in 4. (informal) the courage and determination that it takes to do sth difficult or unpleasant. So "show your guts" means you challenge to someone to show / demonstrate his courage / determination to do something.

Answer (score 0):

To be *gutsy* is to be courageous or brave. Madara says that they should "show their guts". In other words, they should prove their courage, or show how brave they are by example